# Comparing two text files to EXCLUDE duplicates, and not line-by line. I want to output the exclusion of any duplicate strings, specifically

Tags: python, duplicates, unique

I feel like this isn't that difficult but some reason it is and I'm sleep deprived...so yeah. I've been able to neatly format and isolate the words of interests from two long .txt files. I've searched around StackOverflow and I can only seem to find line-by-line comparisons (which specifically seeks out duplicate strings and I'm trying to do the exact opposite), so it is not at all what I'm looking for. My objective is to check whether the same string appears ANYWHERE in (as in, is duplicated) in either txt file (I'm comparing just two) and the resultant output should exclude any and all duplicates and written to a .txt file or at least printed to the console. I've read the Python documentation and am aware of set(). I don't mind tips on that, but is there another way to go about it?

edit: it is solely a string of (numerous) five numeric characters, if that helps. Thank you in advance!

Both .txt files I'm comparing look like this essentially (I have had to change it a bit, but it is same exact idea).

1-94823  Words   Words   a numeric percentage  time lapsed

2-84729  Words   Words   a numeric percentage  time lapsed

The whole document, line-by-line is like that however there is some overlap between these two txt files and I am solely interested in the five digit number after the dash. I apologize my title is/was unclear, I want to compare every instance of these five digit numbers from both txt files and specifically exclude duplicates found if anything matches up in either of the two txt files, not just line-by-line and output that (there are a fair number of duplicates).

Thanks,
Amelia

Comment: Could you provide any example of what are you trying to do?

Comment: Of course! Basically there are two long txt files and every line contains a number from 1 to hundreds followed by a dash and a 5 digit number. There is other info on the same line, but irrelevant. So basically at the start it looks like 1-38473 then a bunch of words tabbed. All I care about is the 5 digit number after the dash at the beginning of every new line. I have isolated the five digit nums but now I can looking to compare it to a second .txt file. Some of the five digit nums are duplicated, some aren't between the two files. I want to output non-duplicated five digit numbers.

Comment: If you need further clarification and if this was not clear enough please let me know.

Comment: I updated my post a bit and hopefully it's helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you have a list of those 5 digit number you can do this:

List of numbers:

```
list1 = [12345, 67890, 13579]
list2 = [54321, 67890, 11235]
```

Create the sets:

```
set1 = set(list1)
set2 = set(list2)
```

Get the union without the intersection

```
non_duplicates_list = list(set1.symmetric_difference(set2))
```

and the result is:

```
[11235, 13579, 54321, 12345]
```

If there is any problem let me know :)

Comment: You're an absolute lifesaver! Thank you so much. I've already gotten it working and I was agonizing it over for quite awhile. I have verified it. I had already isolated the numbers like I said so you pushed me in the right direction and I thank you so much.